# Android: GridView ImageAdapter can't refer to R.drawable icons - They are missing 

Tags: android, gridview

I've run the HelloWorld without problem, but the GridView will not work.
The Sample_0, Sample_1, etc icons are not visible in the R class within the ImageAdapter file.
They ARE visible within the main class.

Going back to the HelloWorld example, I noticed there is an 'icon' in each drawable for three resolutions.
So as a test, I created a new class to access it, ( and yes I did import android.R)
Sadly, the R class does not refer to icon.png.

The only place where R.drawable.icon exists is in the main class.

Why does my R class (which is correctly generated with a reference to icon.png) not seem to be the same in a new java class file?

Help!
Jurimo

Comment: the import for R, its seems to compile! ?

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the wrong R. You're almost certainly importing `android.R`. You can't do that. You don't need to import R since it's within your package.